# How to execute a remote script using ssh

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I know I can find multiple answers to this question but I have a problem with the result.

I have a Windows PC with a script on it and a Linux PC that has to start the script using ssh.

The problem I am seeing is that for some reason it's using the Linux environment to run the script and not the Windows env. Is this expected and if yes how can I start a remote script (From Linux) and still use the Windows env?

Linux: Python 2.7
Windows: Python 3.4 
My example:
I am running:`ssh user@host "WINDOWS_PYTHON_PATH Script.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` and it fails internally at a copy command 
 
I can't run `ssh user@host "Script.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` because then it will fail to run the script because of the python version.

The way I run the command in Windows is using the same syntax `"Script.py arg1 arg2 arg3"` and it works.

It looks like it's using the Linux env to run the script. I would like to run the script on Windows no matter who triggers it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you install an ssh **server** on windows?

Comment: Yes, I have cygwin with ssh on Windows. I would not be able to run a command without a ssh server on Windows.

Comment: OK.  That wasn't obvious from reading the question.  If it fails internally, then something is up with the code or the environment.  You probably need to post the code, and it probably isn't a problem with remotely executing a script, if it is in fact executing but has a bug.

Comment: I can't post the code. so: 1. If I run the script on windows it works. 2. If I do the same command but triggered by ssh from a Linux env it fails with some python errors because of the version of python that the Linux env has. 3. If I run the script (with ssh) but specify the python executable from Windows I end up with a crash of the script because I am executing some "copy" command inside the script. The reason that fails is because there is no copy in Linux env. But the script was design for Windows so that's why I want to keep the Win env when the script is triggered from a Linux env.

Comment: #2 is impossible, if you think about it.  If you run the ssh from the linux computer to connect to the windows computer, the linux computer is acting as only a dumb terminal.  All the python execution is happening on the windows computer.  The key is to figure out what is different between the cygwin command line environment and the ssh server environment.  PYTHONPATH might be different or non-existent, for instance.

Comment: I think I see the issue. It's actually using the cygwin env(not the Linux env) and not the Windows one. The script it's normally run from cmd on Windows and not from cygwin. I have to make it run from cygwin first and then I think the ssh command will work. Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Since it is `cygwin`, you may need to use `cygpath` properly:
e.g. consider using 

    `ssh user@host /cygdrive/c/python34/python.exe Script.py arg1 arg2 arg3` instead of `C:\python34\python.exe` ... Let me know if this fixes your problem, so that I can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to use `PATH=/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/bin cmd /c` in front of the script call, sth like: `ssh user@host "PATH=/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/bin cmd /c script"` .This will run the script using in Windows env.

In my case the problem was that the script was run under cygwin env and I wanted to be run in a Windows env.

Answer (score 0):

```
scp user@host:/PATH_YOUR_SCRIPT/Script.py Script.py;Script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```